# XML file to AngularJS Charts App

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I have the [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rvcqvz5DDZFny8AH27CG?p=preview) that shows what I have so far. I'm new to angular and having trouble figuring out how to exchange the current static parameters for the chart with data in the xml file I'm uploading. I have the `myApp.service` module getting the xml file and converting it to json using the x2js library, however I'm not sure what to enter into the the function of the controller. There aren't very many helpful resources on the web (I've been trying to figure this out for a day now). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Made a few changes to your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/auvXKqpTMfExyFsVGSH1?p=preview), but I need to know where your 'data.xml' is. You have an example? I can explain what I changed afterwards...

Comment: Sorry mate, I just see `data.xml`.

Comment: http://50.22.49.237/XMLFiles/CL_xml.xml

Comment: It looks like the app gets stuck at the `DataSource.get()` code block in the `script.js` file

Comment: yeah, you need to return that `$http.get` from `DataSource.get`, and use it as the promise it is... `Datasource.get().then(function(data){ /* use data */ })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gDwRC1P40w4rhoeHAnA1?p=preview

I didn't use the XML, I just moved the JSON object you're using to demonstrate the proper use of the service and the `$http` module. You'll have to model the XML data into a useable JSON object yourself...

In the service: return the promise:

```
get: function() {
    return $http.get(
        'data.json', {
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                return JSON.parse(data)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

And then use it in the controller:

```
DataSource.get().then(function(data) {
    //this is where your xml data can be used
    $scope.data = data.data
    $scope.items = ['Selection 1', 'Selection 2'];
    $scope.selection = $scope.items[0];
}, function() {
    console.log('error')
});
```